# Array of arrays in json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I need pass on one json one element how an array of elemnts

Correct json:

```
{
    "issued": true,
    "customer": 451071,
    "invoice_lines": [{
        "quantity": 1,
        "concept": "Renovar Dominio - xxx.org - 1 A\u00f1o(s) (22\/03\/2018 - 21\/03\/2019) + Protecci\u00f3n de ID",
        "amount": 13.15,
        "discount": 0,
        "tax": 21,
        "retention": 0
    }, {
        "quantity": 1,
        "concept": "Renovar Dominio - xxx.net - 1 A\u00f1o(s) (22\/03\/2018 - 21\/03\/2019) + Protecci\u00f3n de ID",
        "amount": 12.73,
        "discount": 0,
        "tax": 21,
        "retention": 0
    }],
    "charges": [{
        "date": "2018-03-05",
        "amount": 74.69,
        "method": "paypal",
        "destination_account": 39720,
        "charged": true
    }],
    "date": "2018-03-05",
    "number": 4
}
```

Well, in my code before json_encode try several ways, but all times get **incorrect json**

```
{
    "issued": true,
    "customer": 451071,
    "invoice_lines": [
        [{
            "quantity": 1,
            "concept": "Renovar Dominio - xxx.org - 1 A\u00f1o(s) (22\/03\/2018 - 21\/03\/2019) + Protecci\u00f3n de ID",
            "amount": 13.15,
            "discount": 0,
            "tax": 21,
            "retention": 0
        }, {
            "quantity": 1,
            "concept": "Renovar Dominio - xxxx.net - 1 A\u00f1o(s) (22\/03\/2018 - 21\/03\/2019) + Protecci\u00f3n de ID",
            "amount": 12.73,
            "discount": 0,
            "tax": 21,
            "retention": 0
        }]
    ],
    "charges": [{
        "date": "2018-03-05",
        "amount": 74.69,
        "method": "paypal",
        "destination_account": 39720,
        "charged": true
    }],
    "date": "2018-03-05",
    "number": 4
}
```

In my php code and try others but get same problem:

```
$invoiceLines = array();

foreach ($whmcsLines as $whmcsLine) {
    $lines = [
        'quantity' => 1,
        'concept' => str_replace("\n","",$whmcsLine->description),
        'amount' => (double)$whmcsLine->amount,
        'discount' => 0,
        'tax' => $whmcsLine->taxed ? 21 : 0,
        'retention' => 0
    ];

    array_push($invoiceLines, $line);

}
```

Edited:

After process all ellemnts I execute:

```
$newInvoice = array(
            'issued' => true,
            'customer' => $this->customerId,
            'invoice_lines'=> array($invoiceLines),
            'charges' => array($paymentLines),
            'date' => $this->lastDate,
            'number' => $this->nextInvoice
        );

$this->someAction(json_encode($newInvoice)));
```

Comment: The code you've included looks correct, but you need to show us what you do with `$invoiceLines` afterwards.

Comment: I don't see a difference between correct and incorrect, was there a copy paste error?

Comment: @Joni There's just one extra array level around `invoice_lines` in the second one. I didn't see it at first either.

Comment: I'd guess it's probably just as simple as accidentally doing `'invoice_lines' => [$invoiceLines]` before you JSON encode.

Comment: Please show where your assigning `$invoiceLines` to the final array.

Comment: ```$newInvoice = array(
   'issued' => true,
   'customer' => $this->customerId,
   'invoice_lines'=> array($invoiceLines),
   'charges' => array($paymentLines),
   'date' => $this->lastDate,
   'number' => $this->nextInvoice
  );
json_encode($newInovice);```

Comment: Please, check out the comments of @Don'tPanic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'invoice_lines'=> array($invoiceLines),
'charges' => array($paymentLines),
```

This is incorrect -- it's wrapping `$invoiceLines` and `$paymentLines` (which are already arrays) in an extra array each.

What you want is simply:

```
'invoice_lines' => $invoiceLines,
'charges' => $paymentLines,
```

Comment: The array around `'charges'` seems to be wanted, because the incorrect JSON is the same as the correct JSON for this part. Right?

Comment: @Syscall If that's the case, then there's probably some other error in how `$paymentLines` is being generated -- it seems very unlikely that it's always supposed to be a single-element array.